# Determining `at` within axis() R

Tags: r, plot

In the **R code below**, I was wondering what should `at =` within the `axis()` command be such that the **"8" numbers labeled** on the **Y axis** appear with ***equal distances*** from each other on the Y axis?

***Note:*** I want the **Y axis** to ONLY have the numbers listed under `labels` and the `points(1 , 3000)` correctly show in the plot.

Here is my **non-working R code:**

```
plot(1, 1, type = "n", xlim = c(0,1.5), ylim = c(1/3, 100000), ann=F, bty="n", 
log="y",yaxt="n")

axis(side=2, at = c(1/3, 1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 1000, 100000),
labels = c("1/3", "1", "3", "10", "30", "100","1000", "100,000"),las=1)

abline(h=c(1/3, 1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 1000, 100000),lty=2,xpd=F)
points(1, 3000, cex=5, pch=20)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them evenly spaced on the log scale, then use

```
at = exp(seq(log(1/3), log(100000), length.out = 8))
```

I would do it like this:

```
plot(1, 1, type = "n", xlim = c(0,1.5), ylim = c(1/3, 100000), ann=F, bty="n", 
log="y",yaxt="n")

y_vals =  exp(seq(log(1/3), log(100000), length.out = 8))
axis(side=2, at = y_vals, labels = prettyNum(y_vals, digits = 3), las = 1)
abline(h = y_vals, lty = 2, xpd = F)

points(1, 3000, cex=5, pch=20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but see, the `abline()`s don't match and also the `points()` doesn't appear correctly? (**Could you please run the entire code with your suggested change**)

Comment: You will have to use the same values for the `abline` as for the `at`. Of course if you only change one then they won't match.

Comment: @parvinkarimi, you can use `axis(2, at = exp(seq(log(1/3), log(100000), length.out = 8)),,
  tck =1, labels = NA,
  lty = 2)` instead of `abline` too for gridlines

Comment: @d.b, thanks, I want the labels on the Y axis to be exactly `labels = c("1/3", "1", "3", "10", "30", "100","1,000", "100,000")`? But then `points(1, 3000)` doesn't show correctly on the right spot in the plot?